# Angular SpringBoot SpringSecurity Application Ajax POST with csrf Token Fails on Token/Header being undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, spring-security, csrf

**Context / As Is**

I'm currently developing an single-page Angular JS application using SpringBoot with a Spring Security implementation. The application is for a 'Study Planner', where student can enter study leave from work in a Calendar. So far we have the student able to log in, and enter details in to the calendar client-side.

**Aim / To Be**

After being able to capture the events addition within our client-side 
javascript, we are attempting to send this to back to our Server using an Ajax POST. Once sent to the server, the aim is then to save this within our database against the student so that it may be loaded next time the student views the calendar.

**Issue**

The issue we are having is around the Ajax POST method, caused I believe by the introduction of a csrf header to the POST in an attempt to get past Spring Security. Without the csrf header, I see the network traffic within Chrome and receive a 403 (unauthorised) error. With the csrf header introduced, there is no network traffic logged, the server is not hit and the ajax "error" function is hit.

**Without CSRF Token**

[image]

1. Student Logs in to their Calendar
2. Student add in an event
3. Alert triggered 'newEventData function'
4. Alert triggered 'we failed'
5. 403 Error in Chrome

   403 (Forbidden)
   "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'."

**With CSRF Token**

[image]

(Adapted from [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax) to be in 'beforesend'. Same happens if I just add the function from the docs to the bottom og my js file)

1. Student Logs in to their Calendar
2. Student add in an event
3. Alert triggered 'newEventData function'
4. Alert triggered 'beforesend'
5. Alert triggered 'we failed'
6. Error thrown

   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': '$(_csrf.headerName}' is not a valid HTTP header field name.

**Areas for Assistance**

- How can I see more information around the Ajax error.
- What could be causing no network traffic to be displayed at all, even though the ajax is firing and returning in to the error.
- Any tips for configuration of the spring security to avoid this (apart from simply turning it off)

**Other Relevant Information**

- We have extended the WebSecurityConfigAdapter

```java
    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    /**
     * Set up url based security
     */
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", 
                "/login.html", "/", "/user","/login")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().logout();
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Set up a service to handle authentication requests
     */
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new
        // BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
     }
```

- We have also extended 'OncePerRequestFilder' (Though none of these System Outs are printing on the Ajax POST)

```java
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    /**
     * Overrides SpringSecurity filter
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In doFilterInternal");
        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        if (csrf != null) {
            System.out.println("csrf is null");
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
            String token = csrf.getToken();
            if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                System.out.println("cookie null token not and token doesnt equal cookie");
                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("doing filter chain");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    }
```

- This is the method we are trying to hit. If I remove the csrf security from our HttpSecurity this is hit fine and prints out all the details.

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/Student/{studentusername}/universitydays")
public void newEvent(String id, String text, String start, String end, @PathVariable String studentusername) {
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(studentusername);
    System.out.println(id);
    System.out.println(start);
    System.out.println(new Date(Long.parseLong(start)));
    System.out.println(new Date(Long.parseLong(end)));
}
```

Apologies for the super long post, this is something I've been looking at for a while but do not have a great understanding of web-app security so am struggling to fit the pieces together. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Scott.

**Update**

After adding in the error parameters suggested by Paqman I now have the following information, but still not sure on how to approach.

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': '${_csrf.headerName}' is not a valid HTTP header field name.
```

[image]

When using my chrome console, these are coming back as text variables. I presume this is incorrect?
[image]

My code in within index.html  header (other pages are loaded in as 'partials') is:

```
<head>
<title>Study Planner</title>
...css files...
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
</head>
```

**Further Update**

We managed to fix the literal string issue described above by using th:content rather than 'content', but this still gave us errors on the header/token being undefined. The actual resolution to our issue I have posted as an answer, but if someone has similar problems on retrieving the meta-data within html files in an Angular project I believe changing the 'content' to 'th:content' may assist.

[See this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669424/cant-create-csrf-token-with-spring-security)

```
<head>
<title>Study Planner</title>
...css files...
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
</head>
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using ? Have you tried using the headers property of $.ajax ? 
var myHeaders = {};
myHeaders[header]=token;
{ beforeSend : function(xhr){ // ...},
   headers : myHeaders
}

Comment: And one more thing, the "error" function take 3 arguments : ( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ). Maybe you'll find some usefull informations in it.

Comment: It seems that you've got a misspelling on the '$(_csrf.headerName}'. You're opening with a '(' but closing with a '}'. Or just check your HTML content and especially the __csrf <meta /> tag which doesn't seem to have a correct value.

Comment: Apologies @Paqman the typo was stackoverflow only as it wouldn't let me C&P out of the alert. I think the problem is around setting the meta, I have these lines:
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
added in to my plain .html page and when inspecting these maintain as strings with the var name. Is this a problem with the page being .html rather than a JSP for example? I didn't code the start of the application but my colleague followed a guide initially so I thought the page type would be OK

Comment: Then it seems that your ${ vars } are not processed. Maybe your html is not parsed, I can't really help you on this point without the project setup. You could try renaming .html files to .jsp as you said.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem ?

Comment: Hi @Paqman I have sorry, will post a full answer to this question in case other's are having issues. I feel like an idiot but a colleague pointed out that if we look at the doFilterInternal method (in 'Other Relevant Information' on the question) we are setting the values into a cookie rather than the session. We simply retrieve the token from the cookie within the js which bypassed the issue of the token and headers coming back as literal strings in the html. Thanks for all the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Also I just added the quesiton 'further update' to detail how I believe we got around the literal string issue (though due to the nature, this was still coming back as undefined). We had to use th:content which I believe is angular-specific syntax

Comment: thanks for your good question. I also forgot the th: at the th:content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much confusion we finally resolved this issue. Though most documentation I found pointed to the csrf token being stored in the session, in our application we override the default SpringSecurity behaviour to store this within a cookie (taken from this [SpringBoot Angular Guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)).

```
 public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

/**
 * Overrides SpringSecurity filter
 */
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    if (csrf != null) {
        System.out.println("csrf is null");
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
        String token = csrf.getToken();
        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
```

Because of this, we seemed to be 'barking up the wrong tree' when following when following the Spring Docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax).

Once realising this, we actually came across some [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax) which guided us to retrieving the token value from the cookie.

**Solution**

We added this function into our javascript to retreive the token:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Set a var to be the value returned by that function

```
 var csrftoken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
```

And finally hard coded (not sure if we'll face problems with this later on) the HEADER, and used the variable created above for the token.

```
function newEventData(ev) {
    $.ajax({
        "url" : "/Student/" + loggedinusername
                     + "/universitydays?id=" + ev.id + "&text="
                     + ev.text + "&start="
                     + Date.parse(ev.start_date) + "&end="
                     + Date.parse(ev.end_date),

        "method" : "POST",
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", csrftoken);
        },
        "success" : function() {

        },
        "error" : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("error: " + errorThrown);
        } 
 });

}
```

Hope this helps others if they come across a similar issue.