# CSRF doesn't get disabled by .csrf().disable()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I'm currently using *Springboot 1.5.8* with *Spring Security* and I'm testing the basic authentication.
I wrote a simple function that permits all authenticated requests to use a test function:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurationBasicAuth{
    
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("test")
            .password("{noop}test");
    }
}
```

and the application is setup to not use the autogenerated password with:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Yet, when I try to do a POST request trough Postman with the Basic Auth on the request to any of the urls I get a **403** saying **"Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'."** even if it's clearly deactivated.
I haven't been able to find a solution in any other post and I'm now not even sure if I'm doing it correclty since the version I'm using is pretty old (and I cant change it unfortunately)

P.S. I also tried to explicitly tell it to not check it by using a similar solution you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854865/spring-boot-securing-same-endpoint-with-csrf-token-and-basicauth) but I still got the same error

P.S.S. pom.xml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>authTest</artifactId>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>basic auth test</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- juli fot tomcat 7-->
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.xdrop</groupId>
            <artifactId>fuzzywuzzy</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

**UPDATE**: this now works, but it also ignores the password I set for the user

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("test")
            .password("{noop}test")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: this now works fine, I had to specify the session policy too

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("test")
            .password("test") // Use {noop} for plain text password (for simplicity)
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.5.8 for starter security

Comment: oh it should be 4.2.3

Comment: You don't need `(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class }`. Remove it. Are your sure that your Spring Security configuration is applied?

Comment: If I do delete the exclude, it will keep using the default password, something that i dont want. As for the spring configuration, it has to be since I only get the error if I try doing the POST request with the class in the project

Comment: Spring Boot is looking for your configuration and removes the defaut configuration automatically. If you get the default configuration, then your configuration is not picked up. What is the package of your `SpringBootApplcation` annotated class? What is the package of your Spring Security configuration?

Comment: BTW: Why is your configuration not extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: If I do extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` i get the error `Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection`

Comment: Pom added to the post

Comment: You didn't configure a authority/role: `auth .inMemoryAuthentication() .withUser("test").password("{noop}test");` This could be the problem.

Comment: Uhh, If i do add a role it works, but it also completely ignore the password set for the user

Comment: Now it also doesn't give me the error if I extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: Updated the post with the current code

Comment: I might have found the reason, [i need to specify the session policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980247/spring-security-authentication-success-with-wrong-password) or else I can get in even by using a wrong password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using the older way of using Spring Security and also resolved the session problem (letting a previously authenticated user not repeat the autentication) by setting the session [just like it's done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980247/spring-security-authentication-success-with-wrong-password)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {//Use WSCA in Spring Security 4.x

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()//Disable csrf
            .cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .sessionManagement()//Specify the session policy or else it wont ask for dredentials in the next request
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("test")
            .password("test")
            .roles("USER");//Specify the role even if not used
    }
}
```